# Eigenvectors of operators on a tensor product Hilbert Space

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

Suppose I have finite dimensional Hilbert spaces $V$, $W$, and an operator $A$ acting on vectors in $V$ such that it has eigenvectors/values $Ax_a=\lambda_ax_a$. In the tensor product space I want to find the most general eigenvectors of operator $A\otimes I$. I think that they are all of the form $x_a\otimes w$ where $w\in W$ is any vector. It's easy to show that $x_a\otimes w$ is an eigenvector: $$(A\otimes I)(x_a \otimes w)=(Ax_a)\otimes w=\lambda_a (x_a\otimes w)$$

Moreover, if $v\otimes w$ is a general pure tensor, and we suppose it is an eigenvector, then we have $$(A\otimes I)(v\otimes w)=(Av)\otimes w=\lambda v\otimes w=(\lambda v)\otimes w$$ which is iff $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$.  But how can I show that the *only* eigenvectors of $A\otimes I$ are of the form $x_a\otimes w$?

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/170758/2451

Answer (score 1):

Your conjecture is not true. Take e.g. $A=I$. Then every tensor $\sum_i v_i\otimes w_i\in V\otimes W$ is an eigenvector of $A\otimes I=I\otimes I=I$.

Comment: This is worrying for me, because in Quantum Mechanics the an entangled system is represented by the tensor product $V\otimes W$ of its constituents. The operator $A$ represents an observable A and its eigenvectors represent the state of the system after measurement. In the entangled system the operator $A\otimes I$ represents the same observable $A$, and only pure states represent non-entangled states of the joint system. So a measurement should always make the system collapse to a pure tensor, and those pure tensors should be eigenvectors of operators. If the eigenvectors are superpositions..

Comment: I think if $A$ has no multiple eigenvectors then your your conjecture is true.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$, eigenvalue of $A\otimes B$ coincide with multiplication of eigenvalue of $A$ and $B$. For this you can see page 708 of Abstract harmonic analysis Hewitt&Ross(same method). 
About your question, Suppose $x\otimes w$ is an eigenvector of $A\otimes I$(thus $x$&$w$ arenot zero), 
$$(A\otimes I)(x\otimes w)=(Ax)\otimes w=\lambda (x\otimes w).$$
We show that $Ax=\lambda x$. If $Ax=b$ then
$$(A\otimes I)(x\otimes w)=(Ax)\otimes w=b\otimes w=\lambda (x\otimes w),$$
thus $(b-\lambda x)\otimes w=0.$ hence $b-\lambda x=0$ and we have result.